# How to lock an ASP.NET MVC controller action depending on a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, concurrency

I need to be able to lock certain set of codes in an MVC action depending on the value of a variable

Below code will lock the entire action

```
public ProductsController : Controller
{
    private static object Lock = new object();

    public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
    {

      lock (Lock)
      {
        //  do my work
      }    
  }
}
```

But I want to allow concurrent threads to be run parallel when value of the 'id' changes

For example lets assume above controller receives below four requests at the same time

```
request A : id=1
request B : id=1
request C : id=2 
request D : id=2
```

with above code these four requests will be processed one after another

But I want (A,B) and (C,D) to run in parallel like below

```
request A & B need to wait till one of them finish their work to get processed 
request C & D need to wait till one of them finish their work to get processed
```

Is this achievable in an MVC environment?

Comment: An MVC controller really isn't the right place for business logic like this.

Comment: The OP hasn't requested to do this in the controller, just in an MVC Environment. This seems a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: @bornfromanegg But they *have* specifically requested to do this in the controller.  It's in the title, and it's in the code shown.

Comment: locking has to happen when MVC action gets called, the lock code doesn't need to be inside the action, I wrote it there for simplicity.

Comment: Servy 's original answer worked for me , only difference I had to declare by ConcurrentDictionary as static since it's a MVC environment.